# Is there an easy way to attach methods to objects that implement the iterable protocol?

Tags: javascript, iterable

I was wondering if there is an easy way to attach methods to all objects that implement the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). The only thing I could come up with is to write a wrapper for iterables and then define methods there. (Snippet below made for demonstration purposes.)

My current solution feels fairly clunky. Is there a better way of adding methods to iterable objects that I'm missing?

```js
class Iterable {
  static *forEach(iterable, fn) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      fn(value);
      yield value;
    }
  }
  
  static *map(iterable, fn) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      yield fn(value);
    }
  }
  
  static *filter(iterable, fn) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      if (fn(value)) yield value;
    }
  }
  
  static *take(iterable, amount) {
    const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (;amount > 0; --amount) {
      const {done, value} = iterator.next();
      if (done) break;
      yield value;
    }
  }
  
  // ... additional iterable methods ...

  constructor(iterable) {
    this.iterable = iterable;
  }
  
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  }
  
  toArray() {
    return Array.from(this);
  }
  
  forEach(fn) {
    return new this.constructor(Iterable.forEach(this, fn));
  }
  
  map(fn) {
    return new this.constructor(Iterable.map(this, fn));
  }

  filter(fn) {
    return new this.constructor(Iterable.filter(this, fn));
  }

  take(amount) {
    return new this.constructor(Iterable.take(this, amount));
  }
  
  // ... additional iterable methods ...
}

const result = new Iterable([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
  .forEach(nr => console.log("initial:", nr)) 
  .filter(nr => nr % 2)
  .forEach(nr => console.log("filtered:", nr))
  .map(nr => nr * 100)
  .forEach(nr => console.log("mapped:", nr))
  .take(2)
  .forEach(nr => console.log("taken:", nr));

console.log("The iterable hasn't started iterating yet.");
console.log("result:", result.toArray()); // <- toArray will start the iteration proccess
```

Comment: Yes, a wrapper is the only way. The problem is that "Iterable" objects are such by duck typing, so you cannot generically influence any and all of them at once. You can either add a mixin to each instance or a wrapper. I feel the latter is better as it doesn't need to change any instances.

Comment: Cases like this are one reason, why i am somewhat waiting for the specification of the [pipeline operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) to finish. Writing something like `function *take<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>)` along with `new Iterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) |> take(5)` (how the functions work slightly changes depending on style used) is imho very close to dot notation.

Comment: @ASDFGerte completely with you on that! Personally I use a ponyfill for the pipeline operator that's actually pretty much as good as the real thing, only a bit more verbose: https://github.com/ivan7237d/antiutils

Comment: @ASDFGerte The difference being that methods are namespaced to a class. If you where to write another `take` function for a different interface (for example [async iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator)) than names don't collide. With the pipeline operator you are just using functions, so if you want to define different functions with the same name you still have to namespace. For example `asyncIterable |> AI.take(5)` and `iterable |> I.take(5)`